# Algebra help manipulate fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just can't seem to get my mind around how the  change happens from
$\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1x_2}$ to 
$1+\frac{x_2}{x_1}$
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's false.
$$\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1 x_2}\stackrel{?}{=}1+\frac{x_2}{x_1}$$
Let $x_1=1,x_2=3$
$$\frac{1+3}{3}\stackrel{?}{=}1+\frac{3}{1}$$
$$\frac{4}{3}\neq 4$$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Wouter's excellent contradiction; notice that

\begin{align}
\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{x_{1}x_{2}} &=\frac{x_1}{x_1 x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_1 x_2} \\
&= \frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_1}
\end{align}
So, taking Wouter's numbers, $x_1=1, x_2=3$
\begin{align}
\text{LHS} \quad \frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1 x_2} &= \frac{1+3}{3} \\
&= \frac{4}{3} \\
\text{RHS} \quad \frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2} &= \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3} \\
&=\frac{3}{3}+\frac{1}{3} \\
&= \frac{4}{3}
\end{align}
Hence LHS = RHS.